# Which other wines taste similar to Georgian Khvanchkara?

Tags: wine, red-wine, europe

Khvanchkara is a red wine of Aleksandrouli, Mujuretuli grapes from a region with the same name in Georgia.

As being mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_wine):

> Khvanchkara is a high-end, naturally semi-sweet red wine made from the Alexandria & Mudzhuretuli grape varieties cultivated in the Khvanchkara vineyards in Racha, Western Georgia. The wine has a strong, distinctive bouquet and a well-balanced tannin profile with flavors of raspberry. It has a dark ruby color. Khvanchkara wine is one of the most popular Georgian semi-sweet wines. It contains 10.5-12.0% alcohol, 3-5% sugar and has 5.0-7.0% titrated acidity. The wine has been made since 1907. It was awarded 2 gold and 4 silver medals at various international exhibitions.

This wine tastes so good, however I could not find it in Europe. I live in the Netherlands (and Italy). Does anyone know which other wines I can find in Europe would taste similar to Khvanchkara?

Comment: Welcome to the site Horotat. I hope you get a good reply to your inquiry.

Comment: Georgian semi-sweet wines are pretty unique, and I think it's unlikely you will find something similar. You can try their other red semi-sweet wines, like Kindzmarauli, Akhasheni, Ojaleshi, Alazani Valley.

Comment: @Zergatul thank you for your suggestions. Can I find these wines you named in Europe?

Comment: Cannot help you with this, I don't live in Europe. I am from Ukraine, and every mall here are filled with Georgian wines.

Comment: @Zergatul well my girlfriend is Russian and brings them from Ukraine everytime :D but it is not convenient. I will search to see if I can find any. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amarone and Valpoliccella Ripasso from Italy are your safest bet. Any wine that’s made with dried grapes (appassimento) will hold some sweetness without moving into the category of dessert wine or fortified (port). These wines should be readily available through the world and may other countries are producing appassimento styles, one I am familiar with is Mayu Carmenere Appassiment from Chile which is fantastic!
You should be able to find any of these styles in most supermarkets or wine retailers. Unfamiliar with the Netherlands but it shouldn’t be too hard to find them and if you are spending time in Italy it’s hard to imagine you haven’t came across Amarone before?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and description. Well, I am bad with names and I do not remember if I have tried Amarone. But next week I will go to Trieste and I will try and update the results here.

Comment: It’s one of Italy’s finest wines. Just ask for an off dry red and they’ll bring you something along the lines I’ve mentioned.

Comment: come si dice off dry in italiano? Secco qualcosa? Chiedo per Amarone secco?

Comment: Sorry don’t speak Italian, love the food and wine tho!

Comment: Oh sorry I just asked how do you say that in italian off dry?

Comment: No apology required. I will expand my answer later to include flavours etc but you really should be able to pick up and cheap but decent appassimento in a supermarket (under €10 a bottle)